# Duplicate args in os.exec* in python

Tags: python

I saw these code in a book Programming Python:

```
import os

parm = 0
while True:
    parm += 1
    pid = os.fork()
    if pid == 0:                                             # copy process
        os.execlp('python', 'python', 'child.py', str(parm)) # overlay program
        assert False, 'error starting program'               # shouldn't return
    else:
        print('Child is', pid)
        if input() == 'q': break
```

Why there are two pythons in `os.execlp`? And it seems that the second one can be any string. What does the second argument do?

Edit: I still don't understand after reading the possibly duplicated question. This is child.py:

```
import os, sys
print('Hello from child', os.getpid(), sys.argv[1])
```

So `argv[1]` is `str(parm)`, `argv[0]` is child.py, isn't it?

Comment: Have you tried the documentation yet?

Answer (score 0):

The first `python` is the name of the executable to run, the second is the value of `argv[0]`.

Comment: But http://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html?highlight=sys.argv#sys.argv says sys.argv[0] is the script itself, how come the second python is argv[0]?

Answer (score 0):

It's its name, that's why it can be any string.

See http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=os.exec#process-management

The document is not structured well, people could have ignored the second paragraph simply because they jump straight to os.exec* thinking contents above are not relevant.